# fixing Memory Issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having a memory issue while pushing/segueing to certain `UIViewControllers [ChallengePrivacySettingViewC]`.

All of component of the `ChallengePrivacySettingViewC` are created programmatically. I have extensively checked all the tools and I can't seem to figure out what is going on. It doesn't seems to be any kind of acyclic reference or weird pointer.

This is the `ViewController` that has being instantiated and allocates about 2 X 60+ MB while checking it through `Allocations` tool.

```swift
class ChallengePrivacySettingViewC:UIViewController{
    deinit {
        print("Got deinit") // this is called
    }
    typealias ChangeHandler = (([Bool]) -> Void)
    var changeHandler: ChangeHandler?

    let menuView = UIView()
    private var tableView:UITableView = {
        let tb = UITableView()
        tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tb
    }()
    lazy var backdropView: UIView = {
        let bdView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        bdView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        return bdView
    }()

    var privacyGroup:[Bool] = [true,false] //get dependency injection
    let menuHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3
    var isPresenting = false

    var dataSource:[ChallengePrivacyModel] = [ChallengePrivacyModel]()

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        transitioningDelegate = self
    }
    fileprivate func setupConstraints() {
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(backdropView)
        view.addSubview(menuView)
        menuView.addSubview(tableView)

        menuView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        menuView.backgroundColor = .white
        menuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        menuView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: menuHeight).isActive = true
        menuView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        menuView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        menuView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView.topAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menuView.bottomAnchor),
        ])

    }
    fileprivate func setup() {
        setupConstraints()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(ChallengePrivacyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false


        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChallengePrivacySettingViewC.handleTap(_:)))
        backdropView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        dataSource = ChallengePrivacyModel.loadData()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        changeHandler?(privacyGroup)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The way I show the viewController:

```swift
 @objc func tapOnPrivacyBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = ChallengePrivacySettingViewC()
        vc.privacyGroup = self.privacyGroup
        vc.changeHandler = { [weak self] privacyGroup in
            self?.privacyGroup = privacyGroup
        }
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

`deinit()` is called every time popping out of the `ChallengePrivacySettingViewC`. There is no dangling reference.

Growth of memory on Allocation tool:

```
 VM: CoreUI image data      122.05 MiB  3
  0x14a75b000   00:51.346.892   60.06 MiB    
  0x13c3ed000   00:51.314.556   60.06 MiB    
  0x138ca5000   00:51.378.480   1.94 MiB
```

I saw this on stack trace for [0x14a75b000 and 0x13c3ed000]:

```
   0 libsystem_kernel.dylib mmap
   1 CoreUI -[_CSIRenditionBlockData _allocateImageBytes]
   2 CoreUI -[_CSIRenditionBlockData initWithPixelWidth:pixelHeight:sourceRowbytes:pixelFormat:]
   3 CoreUI __csiCompressImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions
   4 CoreGraphics CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions
   5 QuartzCore CA::Render::(anonymous namespace)::create_image_from_image_provider(CGImage*, CGImageProvider*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int)
   6 QuartzCore CA::Render::create_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
   7 QuartzCore CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double, double)
   8 QuartzCore CA::Render::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
   9 QuartzCore CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*)
  10 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
  11 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
  12 UIKitCore _afterCACommitHandler
  13 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
  14 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
  15 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
  16 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
  17 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
  18 UIKitCore UIApplicationMain
  19 Company main /Users/Company/Desktop/Original/frontend-current/company/Module/LoginSignup/SignupVC/BankingSetupC.swift:26
  20 libdyld.dylib start
```

Strange bit out of all is that. I will have these 2 chunk of 60MB floating in memory unless I go out of the app. Pressing in home button will reset memory back to normal memory usage. App was never killed on at any point.

Any idea what is going on here ? 
Much appreciated

Comment: I had such an issue with UIGraphics, you can check if you use it somewhere.

Comment: I have bunch of places that I have used UIGraphics. Can you be bit specific on what kind of error that was and were you able to resolve the problem ?

Comment: If you can, just comment where you use it and check. Uigraphics use around 120 mb just for init.

Answer (score -1):

Which method will cause creating a lot of VM: CoreUI image data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).